# Smooth graphics in PhaserJS WebGL

Tags: javascript, graphics, phaser-framework

Drawn graphics in a PhaserJS WebGL setup show these pixelated "*stairs like*" outlines as shown in the picture. How to get them smooth?

[image: 1]

Example:
https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/game-objects/graphics/primitives/line-gradient-stroked

```
var config = {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    type: Phaser.WEBGL,
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    scene: {
        create: create
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function create ()
{
    var graphics = this.add.graphics();

    graphics.lineGradientStyle(128, 0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 1);

    graphics.lineBetween(100, 100, 600, 500);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling antialiasing?

Comment: Yes, I added this to the config but it's still not smooth: render: {
    antialias: false
}

Comment: @Tom is the example, that you referenced (on phaser.io) working, or does it shows _this steps_? Since the example works fine and doesn't show steps on my computer.

Comment: @winner_joiner Thanks for your answer. Yes, the phaser.io does show the steps for me on multiple devices/screens. Does this one show steps for you?: https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/game-objects/graphics/primitives/arc-gradient-filled

Comment: @Tom well I see steps, mostly on the blue and red circle. If you would need a gradient, and the [basic html canvas gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasGradient) would be enough, you could use [Phaser.Textures.CanvasTexture](https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.54.0/Phaser.Textures.CanvasTexture), where you can draw onto the canvas yourself.